# Dynamically add UIButtons to screen

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am developing an Augmented Reality app based on location. It is working perfectly when it shows one object at a time (UIButton) but when there are more, it just shows one of them. I have been researching on how to add several objects to the screen programatically with no success. Each object being represented is taken from an array of mutable dictionaries and I tried adding a button to each one of these dictionaries but then i couldn't find any way to animate them using CGAffineTransform. If anyone has any idea on how to achieve this, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this

```
for( NSMutableDictionary dict in dictionaries) 
{
   float x,y; // Vary these depending on where you want the buttons to be
   UIButton *button = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,height,width)] autorelease];
   [augmentedRealityView addSubview:button];
}
```

For animating them, you can keep a separate array of the UIButtons or put them in the dictionaries and pull them out. You may have had an issue with the buttons being released before they were put on the screen or pulled out of the dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you very much Randall, I will try this approach right now. I'm not sure about the animation because this dictionary is created in viewDidLoad and the animations are performed by another selector but this seems like the best approach so far!